# How do I get the node.js server to sign the request from amazon web services for fine uploader?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, cors, fine-uploader

I am having an issue getting node.js to sign the request from AWS when trying to upload an image to AWS.  Here is what I get in the Chrome console:

```
[Fine Uploader 4.4.0] Parsing template s3.jquery.fineuploader-4.4.0.js:198
[Fine Uploader 4.4.0] Template parsing complete s3.jquery.fineuploader-4.4.0.js:198
[Fine Uploader 4.4.0] Rendering template in DOM. s3.jquery.fineuploader-4.4.0.js:198
[Fine Uploader 4.4.0] Template rendering complete s3.jquery.fineuploader-4.4.0.js:198
[Fine Uploader 4.4.0] Received 1 files or inputs. s3.jquery.fineuploader-4.4.0.js:198
[Fine Uploader 4.4.0] Attempting to validate image. s3.jquery.fineuploader-4.4.0.js:198
[Fine Uploader 4.4.0] Submitting S3 signature request for 0 s3.jquery.fineuploader-4.4.0.js:198
[Fine Uploader 4.4.0] Sending POST request for 0 s3.jquery.fineuploader-4.4.0.js:198
OPTIONS file://192.168.2.16/fine-uploader/_dist/s3/server.js No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. s3.jquery.fineuploader-4.4.0.js:3657
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://192.168.2.16/fine-uploader/_dist/s3/server.js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. default.html:1
[Fine Uploader 4.4.0] POST request for 0 has failed - response code 0 s3.jquery.fineuploader-4.4.0.js:203
[Fine Uploader 4.4.0] Received an empty or invalid response from the server! s3.jquery.fineuploader-4.4.0.js:203
[Fine Uploader 4.4.0] Policy signing failed.  Received an empty or invalid response from the server! s3.jquery.fineuploader-4.4.0.js:203
[Fine Uploader 4.4.0] Received response status 0 with body:  s3.jquery.fineuploader-4.4.0.js:198
```

I realize that I am doing something wrong with the signature but with the very unclear documentation I don't know what to do next.  Here is my HTML, server.js, and CORS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<link href="../../s3/fineuploader-4.4.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../../s3/s3.jquery.fineuploader-4.4.0.js"></script>
<script>
// Wait until the DOM is 'ready'
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fine-uploader").fineUploaderS3({
        debug: true,
        request: {
            endpoint: 'fineuploader1.s3.amazonaws.com'
            // accessKey: 'AKIAICPB2GGIC4VOF2WQ'
        },
        signature: {
            endpoint: '../../s3/server.js'
        },
        uploadSuccess: {
            endpoint: '/s3/success'
        },
        iframeSupport: {
            localBlankPagePath: '/success.html'
        },
        retry: {
           enableAuto: true // defaults to false
        },
        deleteFile: {
            enabled: true,
            endpoint: '/s3handler'
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template">
    <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader">
        <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
            <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
            <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
            <div>Upload a file</div>
        </div>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
            <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
            <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list">
            <li>
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                    <div class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon"></span>
                <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                <a class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                <a class="qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry" href="#">Retry</a>
                <a class="qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete" href="#">Delete</a>
                <span class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>

<title>Fine Uploader default UI</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fine-uploader"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

server.js:

```
var express = require("express"),
crypto = require("crypto"),
aws = require("aws-sdk"),
app = express(),
clientSecretKey = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET_KEY,
// These two keys are only needed if you plan on using the AWS SDK
serverPublicKey = process.env.SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY,
serverSecretKey = process.env.SERVER_SECRET_KEY,
// Set these two values to match your environment
expectedBucket = "fineuploadertest1",
expectedMaxSize = 15000000,
s3;


// Init S3, given your server-side keys.  Only needed if using the AWS SDK.
aws.config.update({
accessKeyId: serverPublicKey,
secretAccessKey: serverSecretKey
});
s3 = new aws.S3();


app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.static(__dirname)); //only needed if serving static content as well
app.listen(8000);

// Handles all signature requests and the success request FU S3 sends after the file is in S3
// You will need to adjust these paths/conditions based on your setup.
app.post("\\192.168.2.16\fine-uploader\_dist\s3\server.js", function(req, res) {
if (req.query.success !== undefined) {
    verifyFileInS3(req, res);
}
else {
    signRequest(req, res);
}
});

// Handles the standard DELETE (file) request sent by Fine Uploader S3.
// Omit if you don't want to support this feature.
app.delete("../../s3/server.js", function(req, res) {
deleteFile(req.query.bucket, req.query.key, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Problem deleting file: " + err);
        res.status(500);
    }

    res.end();
});
});

// Signs any requests.  Delegate to a more specific signer based on type of request.
function signRequest(req, res) {
if (req.body.headers) {
    signRestRequest(req, res);
}
else {
    signPolicy(req, res);
}
}

// Signs multipart (chunked) requests.  Omit if you don't want to support chunking.
function signRestRequest(req, res) {
var stringToSign = req.body.headers,
    signature = crypto.createHmac("sha1", clientSecretKey)
    .update(stringToSign)
    .digest("base64");

var jsonResponse = {
    signature: signature
};

res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

if (isValidRestRequest(stringToSign)) {
    res.end(JSON.stringify(jsonResponse));
}
else {
    res.status(400);
    res.end(JSON.stringify({invalid: true}));
}
}

// Signs "simple" (non-chunked) upload requests.
function signPolicy(req, res) {
var base64Policy = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(req.body)).toString("base64"),
    signature = crypto.createHmac("sha1", clientSecretKey)
    .update(base64Policy)
    .digest("base64");

var jsonResponse = {
    policy: base64Policy,
    signature: signature
};

res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

if (isPolicyValid(req.body)) {
    res.end(JSON.stringify(jsonResponse));
}
else {
    res.status(400);
    res.end(JSON.stringify({invalid: true}));
}
}

// Ensures the REST request is targeting the correct bucket.
// Omit if you don't want to support chunking.
function isValidRestRequest(headerStr) {
return new RegExp("\/" + expectedBucket + "\/.+$").exec(headerStr) != null;
}

// Ensures the policy document associated with a "simple" (non-chunked) request is
// targeting the correct bucket and the max-size is as expected.
// Omit the parsedMaxSize-related code if you don't have a max file size.
function isPolicyValid(policy) {
var bucket, parsedMaxSize;

policy.conditions.forEach(function(condition) {
    if (condition.bucket) {
        bucket = condition.bucket;
    }
    else if (condition instanceof Array && condition[0] === "content-length-range") {
        parsedMaxSize = condition[2];
    }
});

return bucket === expectedBucket && parsedMaxSize === expectedMaxSize.toString();
}

// After the file is in S3, make sure it isn't too big.
// Omit if you don't have a max file size, or add more logic as required.
function verifyFileInS3(req, res) {
function headReceived(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500);
        console.log(err);
        res.end(JSON.stringify({error: "Problem querying S3!"}));
    }
    else if (data.ContentLength > expectedMaxSize) {
        res.status(400);
        res.write(JSON.stringify({error: "Too big!"}));
        deleteFile(req.body.bucket, req.body.key, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Couldn't delete invalid file!");
            }

            res.end();
        });
    }
    else {
        res.end();
    }
}

callS3("head", {
    bucket: req.body.bucket,
    key: req.body.key
}, headReceived);
}

function deleteFile(bucket, key, callback) {
callS3("delete", {
    bucket: bucket,
    key: key
}, callback);
}

function callS3(type, spec, callback) {
s3[type + "Object"]({
    Bucket: spec.bucket,
    Key: spec.key
}, callback)
}
```

CORS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

So according to instruction from the documentation, http://docs.fineuploader.com/quickstart/03-setting_up_server-s3.html, I am to set up a server by downloading it and running it.  However, it does not say anything about signature.  I pointed the signature to the server.js.  I don't know where else to point it.  The documentation about signatures on this page, http://docs.fineuploader.com/endpoint_handlers/amazon-s3.html, does not seem to be helpful at all to me as I don't understand what it's trying to make me do to make it work.  I know these might be dumb issues but I just need pointed in the right direction so I can move forward with this.  I appreciate any help at all.  Thanks so much.  Please let me know if I can provide any further information.

Comment: There is a node.js example for Fine Uploader S3 at https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/blob/master/nodejs/s3/s3handler.js  This is referenced in several places, such as in the S3 endpoint handler doc page.

Comment: Correct.  That's the same thing as posted in my above server.js file that I downloaded from these instructions, http://docs.fineuploader.com/quickstart/03-setting_up_server-s3.html. Did I miss something else I'm supposed to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I'm guessing you have not property set the CLIENT_SECRET_KEY environment variable in your server.  It should be set to the secret key of the same IAM users that corresponds to the public key passed to Fine Uploader S3 during construction of the uploader.

Second, you should be serving your page from a proper web server.  I can tell you are not doing this from the log messages.

Third, why are you commenting out your access key in the JavaScript options?  This is a required option.

There may be other issues with your setup, but these are the most obvious ones at first glance.  The node example provided works just fine, provided you are setting up your server and client correctly.

Comment: I commented out the accesskey because if I don't then I get a console error, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".

Comment: There is definitely not an issue with this configuration option in Fine Uploader S3.  You can't simply comment out required options.  You'll need to determine what aspect of your code is causing the exception.

Comment: So I uncommented out the required portion as you pointed out and so there's now an unexpected identifier.  The only code I touched is listed above so nothing else has been tampered with.  Could this simply be a server issue?  I'm checking with my IT support now to see if this server was set up correctly for this.  This just doesn't sound like an error the server would make happen.  I appreciate you pointing out some possible issues, but it seems that these are not correcting the problem.  Thank you in advance for any further help you may offer.

Comment: As I said, there are a lot of obvious issues with your code, and it's quite difficult to provide assistance unless you get some of the more basic issues fixed first.  You'll need to provide a link to your live app for me to help any further.